# bitcode bundle could not be generated because framework was built without full bitcode

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, bitcode

I'm trying to build a dynamic framework (Module scheme) that needs to have bitcode enabled. I have set the **Enable bitcode** option from **Build Settings** section to **YES** for both the framework project and target.

In the **Other C Flags** section I have set the value **-fembed-bitcode-marker** for **Debug** and **-fembed-bitcode** for Release but the error still occurs when I try to archive the iOS project that uses my framework.

I've also tried to add a new user defined setting **BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE** having the following values:

- **marker** for **Debug**
- **bitcode** for **Release**

The following error still persists

```
 bitcode bundle could not be generated because ... framework was built without full bitcode. All frameworks and dylibs for bitcode must be generated from XCode Archive or Install build file...
```

Any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: were you able to resolve this?  I am looking for the same answer